# WLResourceRequest always throwing error using MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using gradle 2.13, Android SDK 23 and build tools 24.0.0.  Java 1.8 for gradle build

In Android 6.0/Android 5.0.1 I am able to make requests using the WLResourceRequest API, but in Android 4.4.2 it is failing with the error below.

```
{"headers":{},"responseText":"","statusText":"Unexpected errorCode occurred. Please try again.","wlFailureStatus":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","status":0}
```

Here are the logs:

> Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir,
>   referenced from method
>   com.worklight.androidgap.api.WL.doPrepareAssetsWork
>
> Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir,
>   referenced from method
>   com.worklight.nativeandroid.common.WLUtils.getNoBackupFilesDir
>
> Could not find method android.app.Activity.checkSelfPermission,
>   referenced from method
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.hasPermission
>
> Could not find method android.app.Activity.requestPermissions,
>   referenced from method
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.requestPermissions
>
> Could not find method
>   android.webkit.CookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies, referenced
>   from method org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemCookieManager.
>
> Could not find method android.webkit.CookieManager.flush, referenced
>   from method org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemCookieManager.flush
>
> Could not find method
>   android.webkit.WebViewClient.onReceivedClientCertRequest, referenced
>   from method
>   org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewClient.onReceivedClientCertRequest
>
> Could not find method android.webkit.PermissionRequest.getResources,
>   referenced from method
>   org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient.onPermissionRequest
>
> Could not find method
>   android.webkit.WebChromeClient$FileChooserParams.createIntent,
>   referenced from method
>   org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebChromeClient.onShowFileChooser

Comment: Can you provide a sample application showcasing this error?

Comment: waiting to hear from you...

Comment: Issue is that I was not able to do https service call i was able to do http call from android 4.4.2. $.ajax does https service call well, I think there is a problem with native class which is called throught cordova at line no 10781 in worklightjs(cordova.exec(callback, callback, 'WLNativeXHRPlugin', 'send', [requestOptions]);)

If you need a sample i would provide but please provide your contact

Comment: Please upload to dropbox or google drive. If you cannot, then create a sample you Can upload.

Comment: You want an apk or cordova setup of sample application

Comment: Your email id of dropbox?

Comment: No. Upload it to dropbox and share the download URL.

Comment: sample application link https://www.dropbox.com/s/883wgwj9prcclcm/sample.zip?dl=0

Comment: So i see that there are 2 different issues here. One is a no backup directory, the other one is the app is not able to connect over https. Please let me know which issue is valid, since you say http worked fine.

Comment: https calls are not happening is my issue, "no backup directory" is not an issue i have pasted my warnings as well so that it might help

Comment: idan any update on the issue

Comment: From mail communication to IBM team, it is communicated that ifix might solve the issue, Is it a Client side fix ie codova-plugin-mfp or is it a server side fix, please let us know through mail

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is a bug in the Client SDK that is being investigated in: PI64093 APPS ON ANDROID VERSIONS 4.4.2 AND EARLIER CANNOT CONNECT TOSERVER USING HTTPS IF ONLY TLS 1.2 IS ENABLED

To receive a fix, you should follow-up with IBM Support by opening a PMR (support ticket).